# Maclaurin Series of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

The question is:

Find the first 3 non-zero terms in the MacLaurin series for the function:
$$y =e^{-x^2}$$
I have been told to simply substitute the $-x^2$ into the standard MacLaurin series for $e^x$ like so:
$$e^{(-x^2)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}= 1 + (-x^2) + \frac {{(-x^2)}^2}2 + \frac {{(-x^2)}^3}{3!}+...$$
Giving:
$$e^{-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {{(-x^2)}^n}{n!} = 1 - x^2 + \frac {x^4}2 - \frac {x^6}{3!}+...$$
I realise that this is supposed to be the correct answer, but I can't seem to make it work alongside the definition of MacLaurin series given to me in lectures. We were told that the terms of a MacLaurin series were based on the formula:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
where
$$a_n = \frac {f^n(0)}{n!}$$
assuming $0!=1$.
However, when I use this formula for $e^{-x^2}$, I get the following:
$$a_0x^0=\frac {f^0(0)}{0!}x^0=\frac {e^{-(0)^2}}{1}\times1=\frac 11=1$$
$$a_1x^1=\frac {f^1(0)}{1!}x=\frac {-2(0)e^{-(0)^2}}{1}x=\frac 01x=0$$
$$a_2x^2=\frac {f^2(0)}{1!}x^2=\frac {4(0)^2e^{-(0)^2}}{1}x^2=\frac 01x^2=0$$
and so on. Giving:$$e^{-x^2}=1+0+0+0+...$$
Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Your second derivative is wrong. Also, you shouldn't have any infinite sums of exponentials themselves in any of these equations.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo, I will edit it

Comment: You didn't edit out the erroneous summation signs (in your second and third equations). Also: If $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, what is $f''(x)$, in your opinion? And what, therefore, is $f''(0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution method is probably best for what you are trying to do.

On the other hand, if you want to compute the derivatives of $e^{-x^2}$, then you will have to use a combination of the chain rule and the product rule.

$$f(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

$$f'(x) = -2x e^{-x^2}$$

$$f''(x) = - 2 e^{x^2}+ (-2x)^2 e^{-x^2}  = (4x^2 -2) e^{-x^2}$$

$$f'''(x) = 8x e^{-x^2} - (4x^2 - 2) (2x) e^{-x^2} = (-8x^3 + 12x) e^{-x^2}$$

This yields:

$f(0)=1$, $f'(0) = 0$, $f''(0) = -2$, $f'''(0) = 0$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The second derivative is $$[(-2x)e^{-x^2}]'=(-2+4x^2)e^{-x^2}, $$ which evaluated at $x=0$ gives $-2$.